# Succinct / pythonic method of groupby percentage calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to groupby and calculate the percentage within each respective group over a certain value. I have achieved this by two groupbys into temporary dataframes (group count over a value, and group count), then merging the dataframes before calculating the percentage. I assume there is a more succinct method that doesn't require creating temporary dataframes.

e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'n': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a'],
                    'm': ['j', 'j', 'j', 'j', 'j', 'j', 'f', 'f', 'f'],
                    'v': [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 5]})
```

1. Count groupby on 'n' and 'm' and count

```
dfcount = df.groupby(['n', 'm'])['v'].agg('count').reset_index().rename(columns={'v': 'count'})
```

2. Filter values over 1, then groupby 'n' and 'm' and count

```
dfover1 = df[df['v'] > 1].groupby(['n','m']).count().reset_index().rename(columns={'v': 'over1count'})
```

3. Merge two new dataframes on the groupby columns 'n' and 'm', then calculate the percentage over 1 for those groupbys.

```
dfnew = dfcount.merge(dfover1, on=['n', 'm'])
dfnew['late%'] = (100 * dfnew['over1count'] / dfnew['count']).round(1)
```

|  | n | m | count | latecount | late% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | f | 2 | 2 | 100.0 |
| 1 | a | j | 3 | 2 | 66.7 |
| 2 | c | f | 1 | 1 | 100.0 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use method chaining (pipeline) to avoid using named intermediates:

```
out = (df
   .groupby(['n', 'm'], as_index=False)
   # compute count and latecount
   .agg(**{'count': ('v', 'count'),
           'latecount': ('v', lambda v: len(v[v>1]))
          })
   # filter rows with latecount > 0
   .query('latecount > 0')
   # compute late%
   .assign(**{'late%': lambda d: d['latecount'].div(d['count']).mul(100).round(2)})
)
```

output:

```
   n  m  count  latecount   late%
0  a  f      2          2  100.00
1  a  j      3          2   66.67
3  c  f      1          1  100.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create helper column `later` for count if later `v` values for improve performance instead filtering per groups, for count `True`s aggregate sum:

```
dfnew = (df.assign(later = df['v'] > 1)
           .groupby(['n', 'm'], as_index=False)
           .agg(count=('v', 'count'),
                over1count=('later', 'sum'))
           .query('over1count > 0'))

dfnew['late%'] = (100 * dfnew['over1count'] / dfnew['count']).round(1)

print (dfnew)
   n  m  count  over1count  late%
0  a  f      2           2  100.0
1  a  j      3           2   66.7
3  c  f      1           1  100.0
```